# React Native, How to get FormData in WebView

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am performing operations with WebView in the application I developed in React-Native, how can I access this data, the data is available in the formData on the redirected page?

Comment: did you direct the webview to a URL?

Answer (score 0):

You must use injectedJavaScript and pass a string, try this:

```
<WebView
    style={styles.webView}
    scrollEnabled={true}
    source={{ uri: 'https://myweb.com/tokenization?type=datasave&test=yes' }}    
    injectedJavaScript={`window.token=${token}; window.currencyValue={currencyValue}; window.paymentValue=${paymentValue}`}
/>
```